# Ubuntu 12.04 installer gets stuck at "Where are you?"

Tags: ubuntu, installation, linux-mint, ubuntu-12.04

I have been trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my 60 GB SSD (nothing else on it). I get to the stage where it is copying files and where you selected your location on the "Where are you?" page. When I hit continue, nothing happens though. It hangs there forever and never actually continues.

I tried a Linux Mint 13 Cinnamon installer as well and same results.

What can I do to get either Ubuntu 12.04 or Linux Mint 13 Cinnamon working?

Answer (score 1):

> It hangs there forever

Please define this a little more precisely. If I remember correctly, this is a point where the setup might hang for several minutes before continuing.

Another thing you can try would be to try installing the system while your computer is not connected to any network, maybe the setup tries to connect to some server at that point and isn't reaching it.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit bug report or try to patch it yourself.

If you don't know how to do this you can try earlier version of ubuntu/mint and upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I would also (in addition to the other answers), try updating the firmware on the SSD.  Sometimes old firmware can do weird things.